# Hecke operator acting on Siegel modular forms

Tags: modular-forms, siegel-modular-forms, hecke-operators

Let $F,G$ be Hecke eigenforms of weight $k$ and genus $2$. For any Hecke operator $T$ (either $T_q$ or $T_{q^2}$) let $\lambda_T(\star)$ be the correspondent eigenvalue.

Assume that there exists a prime $p$ such that $\lambda_T(F)\equiv\lambda_T(G)\pmod{p}$ for every $T$, where the congruence takes place in the ring of integers of some number field. Further, assume that $\Xi:=F+G$ has rational Fourier coefficient with $p$-order $\ge 0$ (i.e. $p$ divides no denominator).

If we apply the element of the Hecke algebra $\Delta_q:=T_q-\lambda_q(G)$ to $\Xi$ (where $q$ is any prime), we see that
$$\Delta_q \Xi=(\lambda_q(F)-\lambda_q(G)) F=\omega_q p F$$
for some algebraic integer $\omega_q$. I cannot really remember why (something like the fact that $T_q$ could be expressed as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear application in $\mathcal{S}_{k}$) but I was convinced at some point that $\Delta_q$ acts on the Fourier coefficients of $\Xi$ without introducing denominators, so we can say that $\Delta_q \Xi$ is still a cusp form with rational coefficients and $p$-order $\ge 0$. From all this, assuming there exists some $q$ such that $\omega_q$ is coprime with $p$, we would deduce that $F$ has rational coefficients with $p$-order $\ge -1$.

> > For the project I am working on, I really need $F$ to be of $p$-order $\ge 0$. My hope is that, for some $q$, the operator $\Delta_q$ acts on $\Xi$ by introducing an additional factor of $p$, due to the fact that $F$ and $G$ are related by this special prime.

Is there anything obviously wrong in my discussion? Or can you provide some counter-example to show why my expectation is not true in general?

Comment: Are you assuming that $\lambda_T(F) \equiv \lambda_T(G) \mod p$ for all Hecke operators $T$, or just for one between $T_p$ or $T_{p^2}$ that you assume fixed from the first paragraph?

Comment: It seems you meant the congruence is $\mathcal{O}_{K,(p)}$ and $\Xi$ has coefficients in it

Comment: @reuns Mh you're right, although I am assuming that $\Xi$ indeed has rational coefficients (which does not imply the same for both $F$ and $G$)

Comment: @user94041 $p$ is one fixed prime such that the congruence holds for every choice of $T$ (so for every $T_q$ and every $T_{q^2}$). I've edited the question for more clarity.